# Start userform multipage into a specific page

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have a Userform named *SheetBox*

*SheetBox* contains a 3-page multipage window

> "page1" for selecting sheets to import
>  "page2" contains a pseudo
>   progress bar
>  "page3" for selecting sheets to protect

What I need now is a method to open a specific page upon opening the Userform when a button on a worksheet is clicked

ex:
**ImportBttn** opens page1 of userform
**ProtctBttn** opens page3 of userform

I'm doing this to reduce the number of userform I needed to create, instead of creating 3 separate userforms. This also helps reduce the filesize.

Answer (score 12):

This works too

```
Sub ImportBttn_Click()
Load SheetBox: SheetBox.MultiPage1.Value = 0: SheetBox.Show
End Sub

Sub ProtctBttn_Click()
Load SheetBox: SheetBox.MultiPage1.Value = 2: SheetBox.Show
End Sub
```

this loads sheetbox first, changes the multipage page and shows it afterwards

but thanks for the caller method, will be useful when I need to know what button gets pressed

Answer (score 8):

In the UserForms `Initialise` Event, use `Application.Caller` to detect which button on the worksheet was pressed, and then set the `multipage`

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Select Case Application.Caller
Case "ImportBttn"
`1st tab
Me.MultiPage1.Value = 0
Case "ProtctBttn"
`3rd tab
Me.MultiPage1.Value = 2
End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

My project using several multiPages. Since the user-defined names for the tabs are dynamic, I set the default Tab with ...

```
Sub iconDailyEntry_Click()
    Call init_GUI(frmGUI.mulGUI, "pgDaily")
End Sub

Sub init_GUI(mPage As MSForms.MultiPage, pgName As String)
  mPage.Value = mPage(pgName).Index
  mPage.Parent.Show
End Function
```

Rinse & repeat for each button's click event. Cheers.